# creating Electron JS executable file ( electron-builder or electron-forge )

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

I have an electron app and now I need to get an executable file for it.

I am worried which tool to use electron-builder or electron-forge.

I tried to use electron-builder and configuration it, because I need to install the app with steps like accepting eula license agreement, select folder for installation, ask for running after the installation finished etc. It looks like everything work with electron-builder and its very easy.
My question is can I do the same configs using electron-forge or the only way is to package with electron-forge and then build a single setup EXE file using for example INNO SETUP COMPILER ( and do those configs via INNO SETUP ) ?

The second: Which tool is the best for auto updates?

Answer (score 0):

For the auto updates you can check this one [Electron - autoUpdater](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/auto-updater)